# Bootstrap Carousel unable to slide

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make a slideshow with bootstrap. However the image doesnt change when I click the navigation buttons.

The first image is displayed correctly and the navigation buttons are visible.

```
    <html lang=“en”>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>About</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://foto.qaz.dk/malta2013/DSC02744_v1.jpg" alt="Birdie" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://foto.qaz.dk/malta2013/DSC02834_v1.jpg" alt="phone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end carousel -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery plugins compiled and minified -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, there's a couple syntax problems:

You need an **http:** before `//ajax.google...`

And I'm fairly sure this backslash isn't supposed to be there: `<\/script>`

Then, check your source to ensure jquery is being linked correctly.

Comment: it was the missing http: that caused the problem. Thank you